# java - can't create a constructor

Tags: java, object, constructor, instance

```
class Human{

    // declared instance variables 
    String name;
    int age;

    // instance method
    void speak(){
        System.out.println("My name is: " + name);
    }

    int calculateYearsToRetirement(){
        int yearsLeft = 65 - age;
        return yearsLeft;
    }

    int getAge(){
        return age;
    }

    String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    // so when I create an instance, i can't have constructor?
    // error here
    Human(int age){
        age = this.age;
    }
}



}
public class GettersAndReturnValue {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // error here because I created a constructor Human(int a)
        Human human1 = new Human();
        human1.name = "Joe";
        human1.age = 25;

        human1.speak();
        int years = human1.calculateYearsToRetirement();

        System.out.println("Years till retirements " + years);

        int age = human1.getAge();
        System.out.println(age);
    }

}
```

I tried to create a constructor Human(int age) to practice 'this' keyword and to change the age from 25 to something else but I get an error because I have one Human class and one Human constructor.  When I try to create an instance of Human Type in my main method, eclipse is asking me to remove the constructor

Comment: First define a constructor `public Human ( int a )`, along with `no-args constructor ( if need be )` inside the `Human` class, only then you can use that inside the `main` method of `GettersAndReturnValue` class, while creating an object of the class.

Comment: "*eclipse is asking me to remove the constructor*" And what does it tell you? The compiler messages are not for nothing.

Comment: Also "*I get an error because I have one Human class and one Human constructor*", why do you think this is the reason?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help!
In my main method, I wrote
Human(5); // I thought this would call the Human constructor but I wasn't
                  // using the human object I created.. I should've put
                  // Human Human1 = new Human(5);

Answer (score 2):

You've swapped the order in your assignment,

```
Human(int age){
    age = this.age;
}
```

should be something like (don't forget to initialize `name` too)

```
Human(int age){
    this.age = age;
    this.name = "Unknown";
}
```

You're assigning the default value `0` to the passed in parameter. If you provide a constructor then the compiler will no longer insert the default constructor,

```
Human() {
    this.age = 0;
    this.name = "Unknown";
}
```

and you might as well add a constructor that takes the name,

```
Human(int age, String name) {
    this.age = age;
    this.name = name;
}
```

then you could call it (in `main`) like

```
Human human1 = new Human(25, "Joe");
// human1.name = "Joe";
// human1.age = 25;
```

Comment: Ahha, I missed that the constructor is already created. I thought, the OP never did created one :-)

Comment: The constructor should not be `public`?

Comment: @akhil_mittal A constructor might be `public`, `private`, `protected` *or* (as in this case) `default` (a.k.a `package level`).

Comment: @akhil_mittal It doesn't have to. The visibility modifier depends on what you want to expose it to.

Comment: Yea right. But it should be public if it needs to be instantiated in another package which is usually the scenario.

Comment: @akhil_mittal Actually in all code Iv'e seen constructors are usually not public. A package works as a single unit with a purpose where most of the interaction is done inside it so there's no need for public constructors. You only need them when you want to give an external service to other packages.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The swap is a good catch, but what about the lack of an empty constructor in response to the OP's question?

Comment: Generally you create some classes and package them in a `jar` or so. The intention is that others can also use our code and in my case almost all classes I have seen have public ones.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a non-empty constructor, the empty constructor will not be available anymore. You do can have more than one constructor, but if you want the no-argument constructor along with other, you will have to recreate it.

```
//Please, make it public for constructors
public Human(int age){
   this.age = age; //this.age first, to receive the parameter age
}

public Human() {} //Empty constructor. It doesn't has to be a content.
```

So you call:

```
Human humanOne = new Human(); //Using no-argument constructor
Human humanTwo = new Human(25); //Using constructor with int to set age
```

Comment: Terminology nitpick: if you create a constructor yourself, it's not a "default" constructor.  "Default" by definition is something the compiler supplies by default when you don't provide one.  I usually call this a no-argument constructor.

Comment: You can rephrase: "When you create a non-empty constructor, the empty constructor will not be available anymore.".

Answer (score 1):

You have to *create* a no parameter constructor, because when you are calling `Human h = new Human();`, you are *calling* a no parameter constructor.

Try doing this instead:

```
Human h = new Human(age);
```

Comment: The OP wants to create a `Human` from an empty constructor, why do you tell him to do it differently?

Comment: @user1803551:  What makes you so confident that this is the case?  From what I'm looking at, it's much more likely the case that the OP hadn't realized that their new constructor overtook the default, no-arg constructor.  I'd attribute the fact that they're saying `new Human()` as a mistake and not as intentional.

Comment: @Makoto Nothing. In fact, in a way I was asking the answerer why they think it's *not* the case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working code :

Create a class `GettersAndReturnValue` and add this. **You need a empty constructor.**

```
class Human{

    // declared instance variables 
    String name;
    int age;

    // instance method
    void speak(){
        System.out.println("My name is: " + name);
    }

    int calculateYearsToRetirement(){
        int yearsLeft = 65 - age;
        return yearsLeft;
    }

    int getAge(){
        return age;
    }

    String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    // so when I create an instance, i can't have constructor?
    // error here
    Human(int age){
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Human() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}



public class GettersAndReturnValue {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // error here because I created a constructor Human(int a)
        Human human1 = new Human();
        human1.name = "Joe";
        human1.age = 25;

        human1.speak();
        int years = human1.calculateYearsToRetirement();

        System.out.println("Years till retirements " + years);

        int age = human1.getAge();
        System.out.println(age);
    }

}
```

**Output :**

```
My name is: Joe
Years till retirements 40
25
```

Comment: Don't forget to fix `age = this.age`.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a constructor in the class, it will no longer use the default constructor. In your code, you've created a `public Human(int)` constructor, so there is no default constructor. Because of that, you cannot create human object like this:

```
Human a = new Human();
```

To do that, you have to manually implement a no-argument Human constructor.

Here is a solution:

```
class Human{

    String name;
    int age;

    //default constructor
    public Human (){
    }


    //paramete constructor
    public Human(int a){
        this.age=a;
    }

    void speak(){
        System.out.println("My name is: " + this.name);
    }

    int calculateYearsToRetirement(){
        int yearsLeft = 65 - age;
        return yearsLeft;
    }

    int getAge(){
        return this.age;
    }

    String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
}
```